# Multiple function calls: 'then is undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, promise, async-await

I'm working on a react, redux chatbot with Dialogflow and Firebase. I'm tracking all the conversations to improve the bot.

When someone sends a message for the first time a new conversation is created in the database with `createNewConversation` followed by the `sendMessage` function to push the message to the database.

The problem is that the `conversationId` is still undefined when the `sendMessage` function is fired for the first time.

I thought this could be fixed by using `then` but I'm getting an error (then is undefined):

```
if(this.props.isNewConversation) {
   this.props.createNewConversation()
      .then (() => {
         this.props.sendMessage(this.props.conversationId, message);
      });
}
```

What do I need to change to make this work? Also, is this something that can be done with async/await?

*createNewConversation & setConversationId Action*

```
export const createNewConversation = () => dispatch => {
  Database.ref('chatbot/conversations').push()
    .then(response => {
      dispatch(setConversationId(response.key));
    })
}

export const setConversationId = id => ({
  type: SET_CONVERSATION_ID,
  id
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `createNewConversation` doesn't return anything, just add `return` statement.

```
export const createNewConversation = () => dispatch => {
  return Database.ref('chatbot/conversations').push()
    .then(response => {
      dispatch(setConversationId(response.key));
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the redux lifecycle. You are currently trying to bypass Redux by using promises.

Trigger `sendMessage` on `componentDidUpdate` if `conversationId` is not null/undefined or matches the condition you need.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to return the promise from your `createNewConversation()` something like:

```
export const createNewConversation = () => dispatch => {
  return Database.ref('chatbot/conversations').push()
    .then(response => {
      dispatch(setConversationId(response.key));
    })
}

export const setConversationId = id => ({
  type: SET_CONVERSATION_ID,
  id
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning your promise from `createNewConversation` so that's why your `.then` isn't working. You want to return the promise:

```
export const createNewConversation = () => dispatch => {
  return Database.ref('chatbot/conversations').push()
    .then(response => {
      dispatch(setConversationId(response.key));
    })
}

export const setConversationId = id => ({
  type: SET_CONVERSATION_ID,
  id
});
```

Using async/await:

```
export const createNewConversation = async () => dispatch => {
  return await Database.ref('chatbot/conversations').push()
    .then(response => {
      dispatch(setConversationId(response.key));
    })
}

export const setConversationId = id => ({
  type: SET_CONVERSATION_ID,
  id
});
```